# shared object in pthread

Tags: pthreads, shared

I want to write a sample program in which 16 threads have access to a shared object with huge size like 10gb. I know that I can use `pthread_mutex_t` to get the lock on the object, but how can I make it efficient so that two or more thread can modify disjoint part of the shared object simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create an array of 10 pthread_mutex_t's, one for each 1gb range, and lock the appropriate mutex for the range you'll be modifying?

Comment: thanks. Do you know any example since I am not sure how to manage the range!

Comment: It's hard to give an example without knowing more about your application. Do you have any ideas about how the threads will access the various parts of the shared object?

Answer (score 1):

What about using a sempahore. You can initialize semaphore with number of threads that shares the resources.

```
    /* Includes */ 
#include <unistd.h>     /* Symbolic Constants */ 
#include <sys/types.h>  /* Primitive System Data Types */
#include <errno.h>      /* Errors */
#include <stdio.h>      /* Input/Output */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* General Utilities */
#include <pthread.h>    /* POSIX Threads */
#include <string.h>     /* String handling */
#include <semaphore.h>  /* Semaphore */

void semhandler ( void *ptr );

sem_t mutex;
int cntr=0; /* shared variable */

int main()
{
    int arg[2];
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;

    arg[0] = 0;
    arg[1] = 1;

    /* initialize mutex to 2 to share resource with two threads*/
    /* Seconds Argumnet "0" makes the semaphore local to the process */
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 2);

    pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, (void *) &semhandler, (void *) &arg[0]);
    pthread_create (&thread2, NULL, (void *) &semhandler, (void *) &arg[1]);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&mutex);

    exit(0);
} /* main() */

void semhandler ( void *ptr )
{
    int x;
    x = *((int *) ptr);
    printf("Thrd %d: Waiting to enter critical region...\n", x);
    sem_wait(&mutex);       /* down semaphore */
    if( x == 1 )
        cntr++;

    /* START CRITICAL REGION */
    printf("Thrd %d: Now in critical region...\n", x);
    printf("Thrd %d: New Counter Value: %d\n", x, cntr);
    printf("Thrd %d: Exiting critical region...\n", x);
    /* END CRITICAL REGION */
    sem_post(&mutex);       /* up semaphore */

    pthread_exit(0); /* exit thread */
}
```

Comment: Thanks but What about huge shared object?

Comment: what about adding a "mutex" variable inside the object. Take the mutex before using the object and release it when you are done